# how to leave Iterator by the same object?

Tags: java, iterator

If I create a new object the program is working properly:

```
Iterator iter = Students.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()){
        Student newstudent=(Student) iter.next();
        if (newstudent.getCourse()==2){
            System.out.println(  newstudent.getName());}
```

But if do not like to:

```
Iterator iter = Students.iterator();
  while (iter.hasNext()){
   if (((Student) iter.next()).getCourse()==2){
     System.out.println(( (Student)iter.next()).getName());}//Here it is printing out the next object afther that I have checked
```

How to stay by the same object?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "stay by the same object"? Do you want to perform other methods on the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to advance the iterator you could always consider using a [`PeekingIterator`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r46/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/PeekingIterator.html), which allows you to `peek` at the next element without removing it, e.g.:

```
final Iterator<Student> iter = Iterators.peekingIterator(Students.iterator());

final Student a = iter.peek();
final Student b = iter.peek();
final Student c = iter.next();

assert a == b == c;
```

The `PeekingIterator` is included in [Google's Guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), although it would be easy to roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

Save the current student temporarly:

```
Iterator iter = Students.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()){
  Student currentStudent = (Student) iter.next()
  if (currentStudent.getCourse()==2) {
    System.out.println(currentStudent.getName());
  } //Here it is printing
}
```

Comment: I has made it in the first example. Is there any other possibility?

Comment: No, everytime you call iter.next() it fetches the next element of the collection and the reference to the old one is not accessible anymore if not temporary saved. What is your problem with the first approach?

Answer (score 0):

Because in later case you are invoking `iterator.next()` twice. The `next()` call returns the **current element** pointed by iterator and **moves the cursor** to **next element**. So in your case

```
Iterator iter = Students.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()){
   if (((Student) iter.next()).getCourse()==2){ //--> Student 1 is returned by next() call and iterator points to Student 2 (next in the list)
     System.out.println(( (Student)iter.next()).getName());} //--> Student 2 is returned by next() call
```

its good practice to store the element returned by `iterator.next()` at the beginning of the loop as you did in your first example, to avoid unexpected behaviors

Comment: Is there any possibilitz to do this without storing the iterator?
how can I call the same iterator many times?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call `iter.next()` the current index of iterator is moving forward. So it is required to save the current `Student` object in temporary object. 
Initially
-|
 
[-][-][-][-]

`iter.next()`
---|
[-][-][-][-]

if you call `iter.next()` twise from here 
---------|
[-][-][-][-]

Consider each [-] is student object

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `next()` method only once

```
 while (iter.hasNext()){
 Student student =  (Student) iter.next();
  if (student.getCourse()==2){
     System.out.println(( student.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   if (((Student) iter.next()).getCourse()==2){ //first time next happened
         System.out.println(( (Student)iter.next()).getName());}/  after condition next happened again
```

In short You are checking condition on `N`  and   printing the value on `N+1`(N.next).

What ever you are doing in first approach is the correct one.

Comment: I know. my question is-how to stay by the same iteration?
usage of (( (Student) iter.).getName()) is also not possible

Answer (score 0):

You are calling iter.next() twice in your program. Hence the error!

Comment: I know. my question is-how to stay by the same iteration?
usage of (( (Student) iter.).getName()) is also not possible